# Load page on stored position

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, reload

I'm trying to make a script that stores the position.left and position.top in cookies. 
Where position.left is put in cookieLeft and position.top in cookieTop.
I already managed to load the values and save them into their cookies.

But I don't really know how to let the page reload in the last saved position? (I do know how to read the values of the cookies but i do not know how i can force the browser to reload to that specific position.)

Does someone knows a way to do this? I know it is possible with anchors but i cannot use them for this script. (not compatible)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This wouldn't really be possible with anchors, by the way.  The document would have to include an anchor at the exact point you wanted to scroll to, *and* you'd have to be able to convert co-ordinates into an anchor name.  You'd have the chicken-and-egg situation in that if could calculate which anchor is the relevant one, you'd already have everything you need to just scroll to that point directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery's scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) and [scrollLeft](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("html, body").scrollTop("POSITION TOP FROM COOKIE");
    $("html, body").scrollLeft("POSITION LEFT FROM COOKIE");
});
```